# Measure of goodness-of-fit in Ordinal Logistic Regression with continuous independent variable

Tags: regression, logistic, goodness-of-fit, ordered-logit

In case of the ordinal logistic regression, both of the goodness-of-fit statistics, Pearson and Deviance goodness-of-fit measures, should be used only for models that have reasonably large expected values in each cell. If you have a continuous independent variable or many categorical predictors or some predictors with many values, you may have many cells with small expected values. SPSS warns you about the number of empty cells in your design. In this situation, neither statistic provides a dependable goodness-of-fit test.

So if I have some continuous independent variables then is there any measure of goodness-of-fit? How do I know if my model fitted well or not?

Comment: I'd rather quote the Norusis citation and make explicit reference to the book :-)

Comment: One option (which I think I read about in Hosmer & Lemeshow, but I am not in the office today so can't check) is to simply divide the ordinal logistic into a set of dichotomous logistics and do the checks there.

I will probably be in the office tomorrow and will try to write more.

Comment: I have found those while reading the pdf http://www.norusis.com/pdf/ASPC_v13.pdf (page-78) while searching for ordinal logistic regression in SPSS. I have independent variables that are in proportions along with some ordinal and binary independent variables. Now what should be done?

Comment: Hosmer & Lemeshow recommend to categorize such continuous predictor and they give quidelines how to do it right: See their book "Applied logistic regression"

Comment: I'd love to see an answer in the answers with dummy data, a decent fit, the statistics, a confusion matrix, and a few graphical gross reality checks.